# FPDF: Fill form pdf & prevent future modifications

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have a form pdf that I fill out and save with the [Form Filling Script](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php) from [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

```
<?php

/***************************
  Sample using a PHP array
****************************/

require('fpdm.php');

$fields = array(
    'name'    => 'My Name',
    'datum'   => 'Berlin, 23 February 2017'
);
$oldmask = umask(0);
$pdf = new FPDM('template.pdf');
$pdf->Load($fields, true); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Output('test.pdf');
umask($oldmask);
?>
```

The script works, but the output test.pdf is still editable. How can I  prevent future modifications of the document by the user?

Comment: Hi Adam, I have the same issue, have you find a solution?

Comment: In theory this should work: https://github.com/codeshell/fpdm/pull/31